# Toggle visibility of (plotly.js - scatter) y-axis & traces

Tags: javascript, css, svg, plotly

New to plotly.js
(I am in angular environment)

I wanna put the traces inside of a multi-select drop menu. Same for all the y axis. To be able to toggle the visibility of these. Suggestions...the easy/right way.

I tried to affect the svg containers with css but no effect:

[image]

Comment: The reason is that I have Y axis for every trace to be able to move independent traces on the Y axis when they overlap to compare the curves.  I wanna avoid to long lists, hence having it in a dropdown.

Comment: I guess the easiest would be to make a dropdown menu that sets the value of an ng-model which relates to the right layout object attribute!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For axis:

```
var update = {
    'yaxis.visible': false
};
Plotly.relayout(myDiv, update)
```

For traces:

```
data = [
    {
        line: {width: 5},
        name: "myName1",
        type: "scatter",
        visible: "legendonly", // Plot trace but hide it to the user
        x:  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        y:  [10, 11, 2, 23, 14, 5, 16, 7, 18, 29, 10]
    },
    {
        line: {width: 5},
        name: "myName2",
        type: "scatter",
        visible: "legendonly" ,// Plot trace but hide it to the user
        x:  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        y:  [10, 1, 12, 13, 4, 25, 16, 17, 8, 19, 20]
    }
];

allTraces=document.getElementById("myDiv").data; // Get data from chart AFTER plotting it.

// Find index of trace-object with "name" property  = "text to find":
result = allTraces.findIndex(obj => { 
    return obj.name === "text to find";
}

// Make specified trace visible to user:
Plotly.restyle(document.getElementById("myDiv"), {"visible": true}, [result]);
```